# Copy Records in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular-form

I need to copy selected row values and store as a new record. 
I am using Oracle Apex 4.2 and Tabular Form. 
I need to use checkbox to select the rows and button copy. When i select multiple rows followed by click copy button to copy all the selected row values as new rows and save.

Can anyone Help

Answer (score 0):

## Copying Records Through an APEX Tabular Form Input

The idea of cloning existing records from a single table through an Oracle APEX Tabular Form works without much interference with the default design that you can set up through the APEX wizard for page region content.

1. Build a table with an independent primary key.
2. Suggested to include two auxiliary columns: `COPY_REQUEST` and `COPIED_FROM` for running copy operations.  Specific form elements will map to these columns on the tabular form that will be set up.
3. Build an Oracle stored procedure that can read which records need to be copied.  This procedure will be invoked each time the `SUBMIT` button is pressed.
4. **(optional)** Consider including a suppression of step (3) in the event that there is nothing to process (i.e., no records marked for copying).

### The Working Table for Receiving Input: COPY_ME

[image: COPY_ME Demonstration Table for Supporting Automatic Record Copying]

**TIP:** You will have an easier time if you use the standard TABLE creation wizard.  Designate `CUSTOMER_ID` as the PRIMARY_KEY and have APEX create its standard auto-incrementing functionality on top. (sequence plus trigger set up.)

Here's the sample data I used... though it doesn't matter.  You can put in your own values and be able to verify what happened easily.

[image: COPY_ME Demonstration Table Sample Data]

### The Heavy Lifting:  The Stored Procedure for Cloning Records in COPY_ME

This procedure works with 1 or more records at a time with a special identifier in the `COPY_REQUEST` table.  After the task is done, the procedure cleans up and resets the request value again.

```
 create or replace procedure proc_copy_me_request is

      c_request_code   CONSTANT   char(1):= 'Y';

      cursor copy_cursor is
         SELECT cme.CUSTOMER_ID, cme.CUSTOMER_NAME, cme.CITY, cme.COUNTRY,
                cme.COPY_REQUEST
           FROM copy_me cme
          WHERE cme.COPY_REQUEST = c_request_code
            FOR UPDATE OF cme.COPY_REQUEST;

 BEGIN

 FOR i in copy_cursor LOOP

    INSERT INTO copy_me (customer_name, city, country, copied_from)
    VALUES (i.customer_name, i.city, i.country, i.customer_id);

    UPDATE copy_me
       SET copy_request = null
     WHERE CURRENT OF copy_cursor;

 END LOOP;

 COMMIT;

 END proc_copy_me_request;
```

There is also a column that can be hidden.  It tracks where the record was originally copied from.

> Note that the cursor is using the `FOR UPDATE OF` and `WHERE CURRENT OF` notation.  This is important because the procedure is changing the records that are referenced by it.

### APEX Page Setup Instructions

Set up a standard `FORM` type page and choose the `TABULAR FORM` style.  Follow the set up instructions, taking care to map the correct primary key, and also to the PK sequence object created with the table in the previous steps above.

This is what your page set up will look like after these steps are completed:

[image: COPY_ME Page Configuration on Apex]

1. EDIT The `COPY_REQUEST` Form Value:

   - Under the **column attributes** section, change the Display As option to "simple checkbox"
   - Under the **list of values** section, put a single value under the LOV Definition: **Y** (case sensitive in either way... just be consistent)
2. EDIT The `COPIED_FROM` Form Value:
   Under the **column attributes** section, change the Display As option to "Display as Text(Saves State)".  This is just to prevent users from stepping on this read-only field.  You could also suppress it if it isn't important to know.
3. CREATE a New Process:  **Execute Copy Procedure**

[image: COPY_ME Custom Process Definition Top Page]

This is the bottom of the same configuration page, there are very few things to change or add:

[image: COPY_ME Custom Process Definition Bottom Page]

### Demonstration: Screenshot of COPY_ME Tabular Form Page in Action

The first screenshot below is before the page is tidied up and the checkbox control is put into place.

[image: COPY_ME Tabular Form: First Version]

Plug in some test data and give it at try.  The Page Process created in the step above conditionally invokes the stored procedure that processes all copy requests made at the same time when the `SUBMIT` form button is selected.

[image: COPY_ME Tabular Form: Demonstration Version]

> **COMMENTS:**  If you spend enough time tinkering around with the built-in wizards in Oracle APEX, there are opportunities to learn new design patterns and process flows compatible within the tool.  Adapting your approach can reduce the amount of additional work and frustration.